# Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler

I have no idea why I am getting this?

```
$ which rake
/Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@depot/bin/rake
[~/Sites/work/depot, kamilski81@mac]
$ /Users/kamilski81/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290\@depot/bin/rake test
Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

After I do a "bundle install" I get :

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions 
Installing turn (0.8.2) 
Installing uglifier (1.0.3) 
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./rake
```

and all my gems are installed into ./rake of my root dir...pretty annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you typed `bundle install rake` at some point.

The `bundle` command doesn't take the name of a gem to install. Instead, the parameter "rake" is the name of the folder that you install your bundled gems into.

If you look in your current project folder, you will see a hidden .bundle directory. The config file in there keeps track of how you set up your bundle install options, and it remembers the directory you set for the next time you run bundle install. The easiest thing to do is to remove the option from that config file, and re-run `bundle install` without a third parameter.

The second part of this issue is that different bundles will install their own version of the commands such as `rake`. In order to run the correct version, have bundler run it for you by running `bundle exec rake` instead of just `rake`.

Answer (score 1):

For me adding:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to my Gemfile solved the problem. For some reason I removed it previously. Thanks to Andrew for the tip initially with the .bundle directory.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I know I did not remove it from my Gemfile. I was in the process of installing canvas LMS.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `--development` parameter once to install all development dependencies from rubygems.org .

So if you're trying to run:

```
bundle exec rake build
```

Instead run:

```
bundle --development exec rake build
```

You'll see any missing development dependencies being installed, including `rake 0.9.2`.

Thereafter the `--development` parameter can be removed when you rebuild.

Note that this method also means you *don't* need to add `source http://rubygems.org` to every gem you write.